# How can I bind a model to dropdownlist input with capability of filter of results?

Tags: asp.net-core

I want to design a form in asp.net core, that has a dropdownlist. I want to bind a model to this dropdown that all of column of this model show in dropdown list, and user can select a row, and filter results.

Is there this capability in asp.net core or css or js?

It's my Model: Company.cs

```
public class Company
{
   public int Id { get; set; }

   public string CompanyCode { get; set; }

   public string CompanyName { get; set; }

   public string SubCompanyName { get; set; }
 }
```

It's my form view: Insert.cshtml

```
<form asp-action="Insert">
    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input asp-for="ErrorReportCode" class="form-control" , placeholder="RequestCode" id="txtErrorReportCode" />
        <span asp-validation-for="ErrorReportCode" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input asp-for="ErrorReportDateReport" class="form-control datePicker" type="text" id="txtErrorReportDateReport" placeholder="RequestDate" />
        <span asp-validation-for="ErrorReportDateReport" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.DropDownListFor< ????? >

    </div> 
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="Insert" class="btn-red pull-left" />
    </div>
</form>
```

I want to have a drop down list in my form, that user can select a company according to its specification like CompanyCode, CompanyName and SubcompanyName. In other words I want a DropDownList with multi column.

Also, when user typed one word in text Area of this dropdown, display results in Company table change dynamically. In fact, data will filter.

[image: somthing like this Image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly,dropdownlist value cannot bind a model.I think bind Id of Company is a good choice.If you want to show more than one columns,you can put them together in option value.
Here is a demo(I use fake data to test):

Action

```
public IActionResult Insert() {
            List<Company> l = new List<Company> { new Company {  Id=1, CompanyCode="c1", CompanyName="company1", SubCompanyName="subcompany1"},
                new Company { Id = 2, CompanyCode = "c2", CompanyName = "company2", SubCompanyName = "subcompany2" },
            new Company {  Id=3, CompanyCode="c3", CompanyName="company3", SubCompanyName="subcompany3"}};
            List<SelectListItem> l1 = new List<SelectListItem>();
            foreach(Company c in l) {    
                l1.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = c.CompanyCode + " | " + c.CompanyName + " | " + c.SubCompanyName, Value = c.Id + "" });
            }
            ViewBag.Select = l1;
            return View();
        }
```

View:

```
 <input type="text" list="cars" />
            <datalist id="cars">
                @foreach (var i in ViewBag.Select)
                {
                    <option id=@i.Value>@i.Text</option>
                }
            </datalist>
```

result:

[image]

If you prefer better style,you can look for some 3rd plugin.
Update(add  `<option>CompanyCode | CompanyName | SubCompanyName </option>` in datalist):

```
<input type="text" list="cars" />
            <datalist id="cars">
                <option>CompanyCode | CompanyName | SubCompanyName </option>
                @foreach (var i in ViewBag.Select)
                {
                    <option id=@i.Value>@i.Text</option>
                }

            </datalist>
```

result:
[image]

### update2：

you can also use placeholder:
view:

```
<input type="text" list="cars" placeholder="CompanyCode | CompanyName | SubCompanyName"  style="width:400px"/>
            <datalist id="cars">
                @foreach (var i in ViewBag.Select)
                {
                    <option id=@i.Value>@i.Text</option>
                }
            </datalist>
```

result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help. Is there any way to put a header row at the top of this list to specify name of every column?

Comment: Thank you very much.
I'm beginner in web designing, Could you please explain 3rd plugin more?

Comment: This type of header considers an item of list and when search a word, if header contains of this word, header displays in filtered search list, and if not header doesn't display. Can I have fixed header row that is not an item of list??

Comment: You can try to use placeholder,I have updated my answer with it.